# Animation is not working in Samsung Galaxy s3 in android?

Tags: android, animation

I am making animation effect by referening the  follwing link .
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/custom-popup-window-example/comment-page-1/#comment-1649.

Code :

```
     public class TutorialActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static String TAG = TutorialActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String NULL_STRING = "null";
    private Button mInfoBtn;
    private Animation animShow, animHide;
    private AlertDialog mErrorAlertDialog;
    private boolean isLogOff = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
        mInfoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_info);
        mInfoBtn.setOnClickListener(this);      

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        initPopup();

    }

    /**
     * Used to show the Logoff Popup menu
     */

    private void initPopup() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        final PopupPanel popup = (PopupPanel) findViewById(R.id.popup_window);
        popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.popup_show);
        animHide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.popup_hide);
        popup.startAnimation(animShow);
        final Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                popup.startAnimation(animHide);
                popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        final Button cancelAppointmet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        final Button logoff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoff);

        logoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                popup.startAnimation(animHide);
                popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        cancelAppointmet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popup.startAnimation(animHide);
                popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });


    }



}
```

PopupPanel.java

```
     public class PopupPanel extends LinearLayout {
    private Paint innerPaint, borderPaint;

    public PopupPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PopupPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        innerPaint = new Paint();
        innerPaint.setARGB(225, 0, 0, 0);
        innerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
        borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        borderPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    }

    public void setInnerPaint(Paint innerPaint) {
        this.innerPaint = innerPaint;
    }

    public void setBorderPaint(Paint borderPaint) {
        this.borderPaint = borderPaint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        RectF drawRect = new RectF();
        drawRect.set(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

        canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, innerPaint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, borderPaint);

        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

tutorial.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/header_bg_short" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_info" >
            </Button>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iveMailMinder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/header_text" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tutorilaimage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/heading"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tutorial_android3" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.xxx.com.PopupPanel
        android:id="@+id/popup_window"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/btn_close_name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogoff"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/btn_logoff_name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_cancel_name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </com.xxx.com.PopupPanel>

</FrameLayout>
```

.Code is working in all the devices except **Samsung Galaxy S3**.

I am showing the animation when i click on "Info" button .

**Observed that in S3 ,when i long click on the "Info" button then animation is coming .With normal click event animation is not coming.**

Comment: Did you turn off animation in your test phone? Setting -> Developer options -> Transition animation scale / Window animation scale set to Off?

Comment: I am facing the same problem with S3 updated to 4.2 .Did you find any solution?One more thing, i have added the animation Listener and noticed Only OnAnimationStart is called not the OnAnimationStop..

Comment: Got fixed by simply setting the target SDK to 14

Comment: Did you found any solution for Samsung devices, i am observing issues in S6 and S7 also

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but i fixed it by setting targetSDk in manifest to 14

Comment: But if i apply the targetSDk in manifest to 14 then UI changes are comming in Higer versions(ex: like 4.2).so this will not work for me..

Answer (score 0):

if i put the tragetVersion as 14,then there are some UI changes observed in Higher Versions(like jelly Bean).my intension is with out effecting the UI ,i need to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When i enable the "Fource GPU Rendering",then animations are working in S3.but i need to look in the reaseon